# using data not sorted (nearmrg)

Tags: stata

I am trying to use `nearmrg` on my data files and I keep getting the same error:

> using data not sorted

As I wanted to break down the problem I used very simple test data instead of my real data and the error message still shows up. Now I have the following:

Master.dta:

```
Group   Date
A   15.01.2012
A   15.02.2012
B   15.01.2012
B   15.02.2012
C   15.01.2012
C   15.02.2012
```

Using.dta:

```
Group Date SVarOfInterest1 SVarOfInterest2
A 01.01.2012 1 201
A 15.01.2012 2 202
A 03.02.2012 3 203
A 23.02.2012 4 204
B 03.01.2012 11 211
B 19.01.2012 12 212
B 03.02.2012 13 213
C 20.01.2012 21 221
C 25.01.2012 22 222
C 04.02.2012 23 223
C 03.01.2012 24 224
```

This is the code:

```
nearmrg Group using Using.dta, nearvar(Date) genmatch(SourceDate) lower
using data not sorted
r(5);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that Stata thinks that your using data is not sorted. Even if if looks sorted to you, run the `sort` command on each data file prior to running `nearmrg`.

```
tempfile myTemp
<read in Using file>
sort Group
* save temporary file
save "`myTemp'"

<read in master file>
sort Group
nearmrg Group using `myTemp', nearvar(Date) genmatch(SourceDate) lower
```

As a side note, `nearmrg` is not part of base Stata. It is helpful if you mention that it is a user written package in your question.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried sorting the Data variable before. Since I am not familiar with tempfiles, I did it in the following way:

use Using.dta; 
sort Date; 
save, replace; 
file Using.dta saved; 
use Master.dta; 
sort Date; 
save, replace; 
file Master.dta saved; 
nearmrg Group using Using.dta, nearvar(Date) genmatch(SourceDate) lower; 
> using data not sorted; 
r(5);

If I missed something, I would be thankful for further comments. And thank you for the side note; as I am new to this forum, these tips do help me.

Comment: @Maryna Gulenko Looking a little closer, maybe the program wants you to sort by Group. I'll change my code to reflect that. I would recommend learning about `tempfiles` as well as `preserve/restore`. They can make your projects a lot cleaner (eg, fewer leftover intermediate files in your project folder).

Comment: I tried this as well but I still receive the same error. And thanks for the suggestion with tempfiles and preserve/restore!

Comment: @Maryna Gulenko It sounds like you will have to look for clues in the documentation of this package. The error message you receive `using data not sorted` is certainly caused by some sorting issue. If the package supplies some example with data, it would be good to go through that to see how it works.

Comment: The curious thing is that I went through an example I found (not from the author directly but it looked viable), so I was sure that it will work. But you are right, I will have to dig deeper. With the help of a post in the Statalist forum I just came across another package with which I could solve my problem, so I will follow that for now. Thanks a lot for your help and further suggestions!